# Formatted output arithmetic inserters

Tags: c++, ostream

I have a basic question about the arithmetic inserters; § 27.7.3.6.2/1  [ostream.inserters.arithmetic]:

> When val is of type bool, long, unsigned long, long long, unsigned long long, double, long double, or const void*, the formatting conversion occurs as if it performed the following code fragment:
>
> ```
> bool failed = use_facet<
>   num_put<charT,ostreambuf_iterator<charT,traits> >
>     > (getloc()).put(*this, *this, fill(), val).failed()
> ```

The question is what exact function performs the conversion from a pointer to type to, as Matt McNabb corrected, `const void*`? For instance:

```
int *ip = new int(1);
std::cout << ip; //0xaa33fa67
```

I'm not concerned in an implementation details, I just would like to know what function produces arithmetic result from the pointer. Is it `put` in the example above?

Comment: The pointer is converted to `const void *`, not `long`

Comment: The conversion to `const void *` happens when the pointer is passed to `operator<<(const void *)`.

Comment: I've undertood. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an implicit coversion from any non-pointer to member/member function to `void*`. After this is passed to the stream, it passes it off to `std::num_put::put()` which prints it out as a generic pointer as if by using the `"%p"` format flag.